# How to create a OR mySQL query from a multiple dropdown?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to costruct the following code that will allow me to create a query with multiple `url` in the form of

```
WHERE (url='abc' OR url='def' OR url='ghi')
```

but I am having some syntax difficulties

```
$str ='url="';
foreach($_POST['future_visited_page'] as $vals) {
    $str .= $vals.'" OR url="';
}
$newstr = mysql_real_escape_string($str);
echo rtrim($newstr, ' OR url="');
```

My current outcome is this:

```
url=\"/abc\" OR url=\"/def\" OR url=\"/ghi\" OR url=\
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Have a look at `in` clause.

Comment: Escape `$vals`, not the whole query. Escaping the query escapes your string encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

here you are

```
<?php
$vals = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_POST['future_visited_page']);

echo 'url="'.implode('" OR url="', $vals).'"'
```

Comment: This will leave the OP open to SQL injections.

Comment: Not necessarily, maybe the content of $_POST has been sanitized before (I hope so)

Comment: Since OP is using `mysql_real_escape_string` on the data I'd presume not.

Comment: @MassimilianoArione I get syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in on the first line